# AKS nginx-controller service deployment is failing with "SyncLoadBalancerFailed"

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress, azure-load-balancer

| Type | Reason | Age | From | Message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Normal | EnsuringLoadBalancer | 30s | (x5 over 106s) | service-controller Ensuring load balancer |
| Warning | SyncLoadBalancerFailed | 30s | (x5 over 106s) | service-controller Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: ensure(namespace/nginxservicename): lb(kubernetes-internal) - failed to get subnet: vnet/subnet2 |

Here service-controller is still referring to old deleted node subnet2

Answer (score 0):

```
"SyncLoadBalancerFailed" : service-controller Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: ensure(namespace/nginxservicename): lb(kubernetes-internal) - failed to get subnet: vnet/subnet2
```

Issue resolved after Force stop Azure Kubernetes cluster and then Starting. After restart redeployed the Nginx service and then it started pointing to right subnet.